# Updating the zoom level value with JQUERY slider and mousewheel FORCE LAYOUT d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Here i'm using force layout where i'm having two functions. One with silder and another with mouse wheel, both does zoomin and zoomout functions.
So when i zoom with slider and again with mouse wheel values changes to the previous value. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/208/)

```
var slideFn = function(value) {
//zoom.scale(value).event(svg);
var svg = d3.select('body').select("svg");
var container = svg.select("g");
var h = svg.attr("height"),
    w = svg.attr("width");}

container.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + width / 2 + ", " + height / 2 + ") " +
    "scale(" + value + ") " +
    "translate(" + (-width / 2) + ", " + (-height / 2) + ")");}
function zoomed() {
container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
slideFn(d3.event.scale);
```

Comment: you need to use the same function for mouse wheel and the slider. so when you mouse wheel the slider moves

Comment: Its moving but cant able to update the value (Translate is changing).between mouse wheel zoom and slider zoom

Comment: thats what i mean. so when you move the slider and when you scroll the mousewheel you need them both to call the same logic so they dont collide with eachother (i.e update eachother no matter which one you are using)

Comment: Yes here i have update the plz chk this http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/210/  :( but still problem

Comment: You can change zoom level using slider and then mouse wheel .